# egg yolks and egg whites

Tags: eggs, raw

I was making an old recipe to serve and it is with pineapple, cream cheese, dream whip and other ingredients and it says to beat 2 egg yolks and mix in then beat the 2 egg whites and fold in at no time do you cook this recipe.  You put vanilla wafers for the crust and then layer this pineapple mixture until you have used it all and top with dream whip and refrigerate for at lease 24 hours.

My question is will the egg yolks and egg whites be ok not being cooked?  It has been over 30 years that I have made this and I just can't remember ever using raw eggs.

Answer (score 2):

There is a non-zero risk of getting a salmonella infection from raw eggs.

However- with only 2 eggs that risk is very low. If you are only serving the dish to healthy adults then the repercussions of the potential infection are also minor.

You should understand the risks and then decide whether you are ok with them or not.

If you are not you can always use pasteurized egg product instead.

Personally I have no problem using raw eggs when I cook.

Comment: ... and of course, you should let your guests know about the use of raw eggs. One of them could, e.g., have a medical issue you don't know about.